# Please assist me to create a trigger that insert values that are not null from one table to another with the following examples:

Tags: sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE trgInsertInTableB ON tableA
AFTER INSERT   
    Declare @ID varchar(10);
    Declare @myNO int;
    Declare @A decimal(10,1);
    Declare @B decimal(10,1);
    Declare @C decimal (10,1);
    Declare @D decimal (10,1);

    select @ID   = i.myTbID, 
           @myNo = i.RepeatID, 
           @A    = i.Pt, 
           @B    = i.Pd, 
           @C    = i.Cu, 
           @D    = i.Ni 
    FROM  myTableOne m
    INNER JOIN Inserted I on m.ID = I.ID and m.myNo = I.myNo
    WHERE m.A <> null AND m.B <> null and m.C <> null and m.D <> null
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the actual insert into tableB:

```
CREATE trgInsertInTableB ON tableA
AFTER INSERT   
    INSERT INTO tableB
    SELECT      i.myTbID, 
                i.RepeatID, 
                i.Pt, 
                i.Pd, 
                i.Cu, 
                i.Ni 
    FROM        myTableOne m
    INNER JOIN  inserted i ON m.ID = i.ID AND m.myNo = I.myNo
    WHERE       m.A IS NOT NULL AND 
                m.B IS NOT NULL AND
                m.C IS NOT NULL AND 
                m.D IS NOT NULL
```